# Merging Collections of Many to Many linked Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a many to many relationship between two objects:

```
[Table("AEntities")]
public abstract class AEntity { 
 public int AEntityID { get; set; } 
 public string Description { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

And Tag:

```
public class Tag {
 public int TagID { get; set; }
 public int AEntityID { get; set; }
 public string TagValue { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping Table:

```
public class AEntityTags {
    public int AEntityTagID { get; set; }
    public int TagID { get; set; }
    public int AEntityID { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent Code to define the mapping:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<AEntity>() 
            .HasMany(t => t.Tags)
            .WithMany(p=>p.AEntity) 
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("AEntityID") 
                .MapRightKey("TagID") 
                .ToTable("AEntityTags"));
```

Next I am trying to get a list of distinct tags for a given set of `AEntities`. So if I have three `AEntity` objects in the last I want a list of all the tags on any of these three Entities.

I can currently can accomplish this with the following query:

```
    public IEnumerable<Tag> getTagsOnAEntities(IEnumerable<AEntities> aEntities) {
        IEnumerable<Tag> results = _context.Tags
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(p => p.AEntities.Any(o=>aEntities.Contains(o)));
        return results;
    }
```

When these are used we are forcing an additional lookup to pull the count of times used on projects (i.e. I am printing the `t.TagValue` and `t.AEntities.Count()` when used).

But as might be expected is incredibly slow (~10 seconds) as the number of AEntities (several thousand) and Tags(10's of thousand mappings) grows. I understand where the inefficiency is happening (thousands of DB calls), and am looking for advice on approach as I am having a difficult time determining what the best approach should be. I am having the following difficulties:

1. If I am after overall counts of times a tag is used in the DB I have attempted separately querying the `AEntityTags` table for a count of the `TagID` (faster as it skips loading anything, but still slow) - is there a better way than this staying within EF?
2. Is there an efficient way to determine the number of times a `Tag` is used in some subset of `AEntities`?

Comment: @ManosDilaverakis Thanks, This was better then what I was doing. I knew it was something simple I was overlooking. Also turns out the biggest inefficiency was a chunk of code still based off the previous data model which was functional enough not to fail, but was running incredibly slow. Post it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have something similar to your database handy to test but you might want to try this for performance over your query:

```
IEnumerable<Tag> results = aEntities.SelectMany(e=>e.Tags).Distinct();
```